# Regular Expressions. cant understand how to get the entire name if it start with Mr / Mrs / Ms

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I cant understand how does `re` module work. I performed many attempts to get the entire name if there is only one name or multiple names (surname).

This is the re.compile() format that I'm using to get the name if the string has the the surname optionally:

```
the_formmat = re.compile(r"Mr?s?\.?\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+")
the_string = "this is Mr Samantha Rajapaksa and his wife Mrs. Chalani Rajapaksa. his fathers name is Mr Prabath and his mothers name is Mrs Karunarathnage Dayawathi Bandara Peiris "
print(the_formmat.findall(the_string))
```

I know the use case of the `?` modifier but I don't know where to put it to get the surname if there is one or more.

From the above example I get this output:

```
['Mr Samantha Rajapaksa', 'Mrs. Chalani Rajapaksa', 'Mrs Karunarathnage Dayawathi']
```

The output that I want is:

```
['Mr Samantha Rajapaksa', 'Mrs. Chalani Rajapaksa', 'Mr Prabath', 'Mrs Karunarathnage Dayawathi Bandara Peiris']
```

Comment: Go to regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/AAAUxc/1) to visually test your regex and have explanations

Comment: To catch single or multiple names, you just miss to enclose the last `\s[A-Z][a-z]+` into a group to match zero or more times `(\s[A-Z][a-z]+)*`, possibly a non capturing one `(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)*`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
/(?:Mr|Ms|Mrs)\.?(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)+/
```

Edited thanks to @treuss.

So change your `the_formmat` variable to:

```
the_formmat = re.compile(r"(?:Mr|Ms|Mrs)\.?(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)+")
```

What is does it it checks for Mr/Ms/Mrs, then when there's a space it will keep checking for words starting with an uppercase letter followed by a space until it doesn't match anymore.

You could check [this RegExr link](https://regexr.com/73up0) to learn more.

Comment: You could also consider starting with a word boundary `\bM(?:[rs]|rs)\.?(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird What is the benefit of using a word boundary here? They're new to me.

Comment: @physiqq The word boundary prevents a partial match for example `aMr`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I see what it does now. Thanks, I learned something new!